# Changes in VC Format Settings in VSCode not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have in my `settings.json` the following lines.

```
"C_Cpp.formatting": "vcFormat",
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.function": "sameLine",
```

What I want:

```cpp
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

What it does:

```cpp
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I don't even have a `.vscode` folder in my workspace, and I have not modified the aforementioned settings in `Remote [WSL: Ubuntu]`, where I am working. Yet, the formatter does not do what I'd like for it to do.

In fact, no matter what changes I make to `Vc Format` settings, they are not reflected while formatting code. For instance, adding the following line to `settings.json` makes no difference to the formatter at all.

```
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.space.beforeComma": true,
```

However, switching the formatter to `clangFormat` does work. How do I get `Vc Format` to do what I want it to do?

**Update:** The issue has been resolved. I didn't do anything that I hadn't already tried. I suspect it was a bug that was resolved by an update.

**Update 2:** The issue is plaguing me again. I don't know what is happening here.

Comment: i have the same issue as well, "C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine" isn't responsive

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, my search field was "@ext:ms-vscode.cpptools format":
[image]